# How do I change the Color of the border of a Label created at run-time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The code below is for the dynamic creation of a Label named `Title`, it sets properties as Font, ForeColor etc. related to the Label's `Text`.

```
 Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Title As New Label
    Title.Text = "BROKERS"
    Title.Font = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 30, FontStyle.Bold)
    Me.Controls.Add(Title)
    Title.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Title.Location = New Point((Me.Width / 2), (Me.Height / 2))
    Title.BackColor = Color.Black
    Title.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(220, 50)
    Title.BringToFront()
    Title.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(900, 700)
End Sub
```

This section is supposed colour the border of the Label but it doesn't do so.

```
Private Sub Title_paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 4.0)
    For Each ctr As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctr Is Label Then
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, New  _
                            Rectangle(ctr.Location, ctr.Size))
        End If
    Next
    pen.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the `Paint` event of your Label (or Labels, if you add more than one; use the same event handler for all).

When the Paint event is raised, the `sender` object is the Control that raised the event, so you can cast `sender` to `Control` or `Label` (we just need the `ClientRectangle` property value, which belongs to the `Control` class, so you could use the same event handler for other Controls that are not `Label`; e.g., a Panel).

Now, if you want your Label to auto-size to its Text content, you need to set `AutoSize = True`: the Label will auto-size when its Layout is performed (after you add it to a Container - the Form here).
So, to show it in the middle of the Form, set its `Location` property after you have added it the `Controls` collection and you have changed the Form size.

If you want to set a specific `Size` instead, don't set `AutoSize = False`, set the `Size` Property explicitly and the `Location` Property after you have changed the Form size (it appears you want to resize the Form at run-time).

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Dim lblTitle As New Label() With {
        .AutoSize = True,
        .BackColor = Color.Black,
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        .Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 30, FontStyle.Bold),
        .ForeColor = Color.Red,
        .Text = "BROKERS"
    }

    AddHandler lblTitle.Paint, AddressOf TitleLabel_Paint

    ClientSize = New Size(900, 700)
    Controls.Add(lblTitle)
    lblTitle.Location = New Point(ClientSize.Width - lblTitle.Width) \ 2, 
                                 (ClientSize.Height - lblTitle.Height) \ 2)
End Sub

Private Sub TitleLabel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    If sender Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim ctrl = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    Using pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 4)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ctrl.ClientRectangle)
    End Using
End Sub
```